# Need to transpose data in excel

Tags: excel

I need to transpose a list of names in excel. Specifically, I have accounts with names next to them, but i want them vertical and for each name to be assigned to an account. Please see below for a visualization of what i am trying to achieve. This is just an example and I have hundreds of rows of data so it will need to be some sort of formula.

Current Data:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

I'm a little stuck on how to get there. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Power Query, otherwise known as Get & Transform. Use the option to unpivot columns. See the linked question, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27671495/9245853), not the accepted one. You may need to add the step of deleting a column after unpivoting.

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKuEJ.png) is the result I get using Power Query - so it definitely works.

Comment: I am unable to download Power Query on my work computer, is there another solution?

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: I have excel 2016

Comment: Then you already have Power Query - it's just known as Get and Transform. Check the Data tab.

Comment: Ok, i was able to find the power query editor. However when i open the editor, my data table above does not appear even though i have it selected when i open the editor

Comment: Nevermind, i had to select "from Table/Range"